# Normal ordered product of $4$ scalar fields $X^\mu$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, wick-theorem

I'm trying to get more familiarity with the conformal normal ordering used in Polchinski's String Theory vol. 1 and I'm currently trying to solve problem $2.2$ which asks to prove that the normal ordered product of $4$ fields $X^{\mu_i}(z_i,\bar z_i)$ at different points is harmonic in each coordinate, i.e. that

$$\partial_i\bar \partial_i:X^{\mu_1}X^{\mu_2}X^{\mu_3}X^{\mu_4}:  \ =0  \hspace{1cm} \text{(no sum)} \tag1$$
where $X^{\mu_i} \equiv X^{\mu_i}(z_i,\bar z_i)$. Of course, first I need to find the explicit form of the ordered product before differentiate and that is where my problem lies.

There are two "different" ways of calculate the ordered product of an arbitrary number of scalar fields $X$ presented by Polchinski at the beginning of page $39$(The author defines $z_{ij} = z_i - z_j$).

> The definition of normal ordering for arbitrary numbers of fields can be given recursively as
> $$
> : X^{\mu_1}\left(z_1, \bar{z}_1\right) \ldots X^{\mu_n}\left(z_n, \bar{z}_n\right):
> $$
> $$
> =X^{\mu_1}\left(z_1, \bar{z}_1\right) \ldots X^{\mu_n}\left(z_n, \bar{z}_n\right)+\sum \text { subtractions }
> \tag{2.2.5}$$
> where the sum runs over all ways of choosing one, two, or more pairs of fields from the product and replacing each pair with $\frac{1}{2} \alpha^{\prime} \eta^{\mu_i \mu_j} \ln \left|z_{i j}\right|^2$. For example,
> $$
> \begin{gathered}
> : X^{\mu_1}\left(z_1, \bar{z}_1\right) X^{\mu_2}\left(z_2, \bar{z}_2\right) X^{\mu_3}\left(z_3, \bar{z}_3\right):=X^{\mu_1}\left(z_1, \bar{z}_1\right) X^{\mu_2}\left(z_2, \bar{z}_2\right) X^{\mu_3}\left(z_3, \bar{z}_3\right) \\
> \quad+\left(\frac{\alpha^{\prime}}{2} \eta^{\mu_1 \mu_2} \ln \left|z_{12}\right|^2 X^{\mu_3}\left(z_3, \bar{z}_3\right)+2 \text { permutations }\right)
> \end{gathered}
> \tag{2.2.6}$$
> We leave it to the reader to show that the definition $(2.2 .5)$ retains the desired property that the normal ordered product satisfies the naive equation of motion.
> The definition can be compactly summarized as
> $$
> : \mathscr{F}:=\exp \left(\frac{\alpha^{\prime}}{4} \int d^2 z_1 d^2 z_2 \ln \left|z_{12}\right|^2 \frac{\delta}{\delta X^\mu\left(z_1, \bar{z}_1\right)} \frac{\delta}{\delta X_\mu\left(z_2, \bar{z}_2\right)}\right) \mathscr{F},
> \tag{2.2.7}$$
> where $\mathscr{F}$ is any functional of $X$. This is equivalent to eq. (2.2.5): the double derivative in the exponent contracts each pair of fields, and the exponential sums over any number of pairs with the factorial canceling the number of ways the derivatives can act. (...)

If I follow $(2.2.5)$, the product in $(1)$ is given by

$$:X^{\mu_1}X^{\mu_2}X^{\mu_3}X^{\mu_4}: \ = X^{\mu_1}X^{\mu_2}X^{\mu_3}X^{\mu_4} + \frac{\alpha'}{2} \eta^{\mu_1 \mu_2} \ln|z_{12}|^2 X^{\mu_3}X^{\mu_4} + (\text{$5$ other ways of choosing one pair}) +\\ +  \frac{\alpha'^2}{4} \eta^{\mu_1 \mu_2}\eta^{\mu_3 \mu_4}\ln|z_{12}|^2\ln|z_{34}|^2 + \frac{\alpha'^2}{4}\eta^{\mu_3 \mu_4} \eta^{\mu_1 \mu_2}\ln|z_{34}|^2 \ln|z_{12}|^2 + (\text{other $4$ similar terms}).$$

Note that there are $6$ terms with two pairs, but you can regroup them to form only $3$ since some of them are equal.

If I use $(2.2.7)$, since each integral operator contract two terms of the product, I only need to consider up the second order operator term, which is of the form

$$\frac{1}{2!}\left( \frac{\alpha'}{4}\right)^2 \left( \int d^2z d^2z'\ln |z-z'|^2 \frac{\delta}{\delta X^\mu(z)}\frac{\delta}{\delta X_\mu(z')}\right)^2.$$

Using this the operator formula leads me to the same first $7$ terms as before, but the other $6$ terms formed by two pairs have each an extra factor of $1/2$. Any help with this will be appreciated